# Where can I find a bundle implementing the org.osgi.service.log.LoggerFactory service?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, java-11, osgi-bundle

I am trying to get a minimal OSGI bundle running using the OSGI logging facade (org.osgi.service.log-1.4.0).

When I try retrieving an implementation of the LoggerFactory class I just get `null`. I'm assuming this is because the org.osgi.service.log -bundle does not contain any implementation of its own service.

I understand what's missing in my application is a logging implementation, but I'm struggling with finding a bundle that is able to supply me with this.

Where can I find a simple bundle that provides my environment with an implementation of the org.osgi.service.log service (version 1.4.0)?

Information about my environment:

- Karaf 4.2.7
- Java 11
- org.osgi.service.log-1.4.0

My code can be wiewed [here](https://github.com/hannesknutsson/OSGI-Karaf-example-repository).

Comment: Do you want to experiment with the log service or just want logging? If you just want logging then the simplest way is to use plain slf4j api in your bundle.

Comment: I want the modularity provided by the OSGI logging facade so that I can add and remove different logging implementations during runtime and have this affect how all installed bundles perform their logging.

Comment: I used "plain Apache Felix" for [my attempts](https://github.com/mnlipp/de.mnl.osgi#osgi-logging-bridgesfacades) to redirect all logging to the OSGi 7 log service. You might give it a try to simply replace the logging provider bundle in your karaf with the one from Apache Felix. Log Service 1.4 contributes to OSGi 7 but afaik doesn't depend on anything new in OSGi 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apach Karaf 4.2.x is based on OSGi R6. The [log service](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.log.html) is part of R7 which should be available in Karaf 4.3.x.

Comment: Oh, you're right about that. I've just assumed that it was released since I could use the dependency and all my bundles seemed to install nicely.

I hope they release Karaf 4.3.X soon!

Comment: And it'll be implemented by pax-logging 2.0.0, which is not released yet. See https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXLOGGING-255.